# VBA :Match columns from from workbook A & B, return another column from workbook A to workbook B

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks A & B.The workbooks are already defined.

I have an issue with part of my code where I am trying to compare column A from workbook A and Column D from Workbook B. If it matches then I want to copy corresponding column B to Workbook column E.

I started to write the following code but not sure how to proceed further in comparing the columns and copying as I am fairly new to VBA.

```
Dim strRangeToCheckA As Range
Dim strRangeToCheckB As Range
Dim strRangeToCheckC As Variant

Set strRangeToCheckA = RSC.Sheets("Balance").Range("A:G")
Set strRangeToCheckB = Brostacc.Sheets("Stock").Range("A:U")
Set strRangeToCheckC = Brostacc.Sheets("Stock").Range("U:U")

If Application.VLookup(LookFor, strRangeToCheckA, 2, False) = Application.VLookup(LookFor, strRangeToCheckB, 1, False) Then
  strRangeToCheckC = Application.VLookup(LookFor, strRangeToCheckA, 7, False)
End If
```

Comment: This is not a programming service. What errors do you get?

Comment: @peakpeak I don't get any error, but then I don't get any data in the Output  either. I have updated the code a little bit which I have been trying now.

Comment: are you looking at a per row match across the two columns or the entire column?  Col B is coming from Workbook A to Col E in Workbook B?

Comment: @QHarr No I am not doing per row match, I compare whether the data in col B of workbook A is in col A of wrkbook B, if it is the corresponding col G from workbook A is copied to col E of workbook B